# How to add the point event listener into anychart.stock() on AnyChart?

Tags: anychart

In Anystock/AnyChart, I want to listen to the point event when the mouse clicks.

So, I added the following code as a script.

```
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {

// create data table
var table = anychart.data.table();
// add data
table.addData([
['2015-12-24', 511.53, 514.98, 505.79, 506.40],
['2015-12-25', 512.53, 514.88, 505.69, 510.34],
['2015-12-26', 511.83, 514.98, 505.59, 507.23],
['2015-12-27', 511.22, 515.30, 505.49, 506.47],
['2015-12-28', 511.53, 514.98, 505.79, 506.40],
['2015-12-29', 512.53, 513.88, 505.69, 510.34],
['2015-12-30', 511.83, 512.98, 502.59, 503.23],
['2015-12-31', 511.22, 515.30, 505.49, 506.47],
['2016-01-01', 510.35, 515.72, 505.23, 508.80]
]);

// map loaded data
var mapping = table.mapAs({'open': 1, 'high': 2, 'low': 3, 'close': 4});

// create a stock chart
var chart = anychart.stock();

// add a series using mapping
chart.plot(0).ohlc(mapping).name('ACME Corp. Stock Prices');

// set container id for the chart
chart.container('container');

// initiate chart drawing
chart.draw();

    // add a mount event listener - It is fine.
 chart.listen('click', function(e){
            alert(e);
 });  
    // add a point event listener - It does not work.
  chart.listen('pointClick', function(e){
            alert(e);
 });  
});
```

The mouse event was being raised successfully, but the point event did not work. 
How does we add the point event listener into anychart.stock() on AnyChart? 
If anyone has a solution already, it would be great if you could share it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the current version of AnyStock (8.3.0) doesn't support point related events as basic charts. If you want to show additional information about the point you can show it in the point tooltip using formatter function - https://api.anychart.com/anychart.core.ui.Tooltip#format